# Javascript: get the union of all arrays with the same key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Get the union of all arrays with the same key.

```
const props = {S1: {vals: [1, 2, 3, 4], ...}, S2: {vals: [3, 4, 5, 6], ...}}
```

And I want an array with the values:

```
const res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I am trying to use `reduce` and `map` with the following attempt:

```
const res = Object.entries(props).reduce((res, o) => res.union(Object.entries([k, v]) => v[vals]);
```

How to format the map reduce operation in such a way that it works?

Comment: Are your props always S1 and S2 or are they variable?

`const res = [new Set([...props.S1.vals, ...props.S2.vals])];`

Comment: It can be anything and can be very long. Hard coding is not desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of `props` as an array first, then [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)-ping to the desired property (`vals`), and finally removing duplicate values using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const props = {
  S1: {
    vals: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  },
  S2: {
    vals: [3, 4, 5, 6],
  }
};

const union = [...new Set(Object.values(props).flatMap(({ vals }) => vals))];

console.log(union);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach by checking the value:

- if array return the items,
- if not take the values from the object and map the result of calling the function again.

At the end get unique values.

```js
const
    getValues = v => Array.isArray(v)
        ? v
        : Object.values(v).flatMap(getValues),
    props = { S1: { vals: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, S2: { vals: [3, 4, 5, 6] } },
    values = [...new Set(getValues(props))];

console.log(...values);
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to unionize all the array, only the arrays with a specific key.

Comment: which one do you want?

Comment: I want the union of all arrays with the key vals or something like that. vr.'s answer works well for my case.

Answer (score 1):

The following method does not use reduce but is a more readable way to get the same result.

```js
function extractValues (obj) {
    // Find keys from Object
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    // Then we select each child object using the keys we found and read the vals value.
    const values = keys.map(key => obj[key].vals);
    // Then we convert the values into a single Array, since the data we get is in the form [Array, Array, ...]
    const flat = values.flat();
    // Finally, we remove duplicate data.
    const unique = Array.from(new Set(flat));

    return unique;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values()` with `Array.reduce()` like so:

```js
const props = {S1: {vals: [1, 2, 3, 4]}, S2: {vals: [3, 4, 5, 6]}};

const result = Object.values(props).reduce((acc, o) => {
    return [
        ...acc,
        ...o.vals.filter(v => !acc.includes(v))
    ];
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it with Sets, without creating new Sets for each of the objects in the original (`props`):

```
const allvals = Array.from(Object.values(props)
  .reduce((set, { vals }) => (
    vals.forEach(set.add, set),
    set
  ), new Set())
  .values());
```

That iterates through the values (because the property names in the outer object don't appear to be important) with `.reduce()` to build a Set instance, but only one Set is created. The Set class doesn't have a method to add all elements of an array.